# Does os.listdir(path) include the special entries '.' and '..'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev

The path I am trying to access is `../Pictures/NewYork`

```
self.path = "../Pictures/NewYork"
self.files = os.listdir(self.path )
```

I am getting an error message saying that

```
The system cannot find the path specified: '../Pictures/NewYork/*.*'
```

Is there a better way to go up a level?

Comment: That can't be your code. Where is the glob pattern coming from?

Comment: and .. is a perfectly acceptable path, without needing to convert.

Comment: `../Pictures/NewYork` works, *provided your current working directory* has such a sibling directory. What does the output of `os.getcwd()` tell you?

Comment: The class is too long to post it here, the only issue I am having is with the path.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: relative paths work just fine. At issue is that there really is no such path *relative to the current working directory*. Using `os.path.abspath()` without a better reference than `os.getcwd()` is not going to help here.

Comment: @pvg AIUI Python adds the wildcard in order to pass to the native windows FindFirstFile system call, so just because that's there doesn't mean his code put it in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, my bad

Comment: @pvg: the `*.*` comes from the [Windows implementation for the `os.listdir()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l2319), and is not removed [when the exception object is created](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/posixmodule.c#l2335) if there is no such directory.

Comment: @Random832 and that shows up in error messages? Terrifying.

Comment: You can sanity check your paths with `assert 'Pictures' in os.listdir('..'), 'have pictures'` and `assert 'NewYork' in os.listdir('../Pictures'), 'have NewYork'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guest... You want to go up from the place where the py file is?

`os.listdir("../Pictures/NewYork")` will be relative to the *current working directory* which could be anything.

If my guess is right, you want this:

```
this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
new_york_dir = os.path.join(this_dir, '..', 'Pictures', 'NewYork')
files = os.path.listdir(new_york_dir)
```